# Notebook display not working properly

Tags: laptop, display

I have an old Acer TM4001 notebook. If the laptop is powered-off, with the lid closed, when I power it on, it generally works. Then, without touching anything, if I reboot the computer the internal display will not work anymore. To make it working again I need to shut down the pc, close and reopen the lid and then turn it on. If I close and reopen the lid if it is not working after power the pc on, it won't work.

When the screen is working, closing and opening it has no effect (the data cable seems ok).
The external monitor always works as expected: If the internal display is not detected, the external will be the main (and only) display so it's not a backlight failure.
This is not OS-related. When the screen is not working I cannot see the POST.

What could be the cause for this?

Answer (score 0):

The switch or the backlight.

Some backlight failures (FL Inverters) can be seen first in odd and random turning off/turning on behavior. To tell if this is the issue: When the screen is not working, or appear blank, cup your hands over the screen or view it in a darkened room and see if you can see dim images on the screen. If you see dim images on the screen, such as your mouse cursor moving, your issue is the backlight.

If you cannot see anything on the screen, even in a darkened room, the issue is probably the switch the laptop uses to tell if the screen is open or closed to turn the backlight off or on.

Comment: There are no dim images on the screen. Also, when an external display is connected I can see that there is only one display detected.
It's probably not the switch also. If it were the switch I guess I would have no issues when I dont't touch the laptop's lid between reboots. And when the screen is on, The lid switch works fine.